# How to display data from a factory using controller through ng-click with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to return some data, through ng-click, using factory and controller, and I can see it back, but am not able to display it.

This is my html: 
    `

```
<div ng-controller="TokensCtrl">
    <a type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#tokens" ng-    click="getTokens(child.ChildId)" >Get Tokens</a>
    </div>`
```

,

ng-click should return data to the modal:

```
`<div id="tokens" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Tokens:</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" ng-controller="TokensCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat='token in tokens'>
      <li>{{token}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>`
```

this is the factory:

```
` 
kindergardenApp.factory('tokens', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = '/admin/GetChildTokens';
    var tokens = {};

    tokens.getTokens = function (id) {
        return $http({
            url: urlBase,
            method: 'GET',
            params: {id: id}
        });
    };

    return tokens;
}]);`
```

and the controller:

```
`kindergardenApp.controller('TokensCtrl',
    function ($scope, tokens) {
        $scope.token = 'none';
        $scope.status;

        $scope.getTokens = function (id) {
            tokens.getTokens(id)
                .success(function (tokens) {
                    $scope.tokens = tokens;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = "Unable to get tokens: " + error.message;
                })
        }
    }
)`
```

How to make it work?
Edit: It almost works, I can't figure out why does it return only the first set of tokens, of the first record. In the controller it passes the right ID, it returns the right tokens according to the ID, but when time to display, if I choose anything else than the first one it shows nothing. If I choose the first one first, then all others show the same data. And in the console it still shows the right data..

This is the html now, till I make it look prettier:

`

```
<div ng-controller="ChildrenCtrl">
    <a class="btn btn-success add" data-toggle="modal" href="#addKid" role="button">Add A Child</a>    
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table chldrenadmin">
    <tr ng-repeat="child in $data" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
        <td data-title="'Name'" ng-bind="child.Name" ng-class="name"></td>
        <td data-title="'Age'" ng-bind="3"></td>
        <td data-title="'EGN'" ng-bind="child.EGN"></td>
        <td data-title="'Edit Record'"><input type="button" value="Edit" /></td>
        <td data-title="'Delete'"><div ng-controller="ChildrenDataCtrl"><input type="button" class="removekid" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteKid(child.ChilfdId)" ng-model="child.ChildId"/></div></td>
        <td data-title="'Tokens'">
            <div ng-controller="TokensCtrl"><a href="#tokensModal" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="getTokens(child.ChildId)" ng-model="child.ChildId">Get Tokens{{child.ChildId}}</a>
                <div id="tokensModal" class="modal fade tokens" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h3>Tokens:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul ng-repeat='token in tokens'>
                            <li><input value={{token}} />{{tokens}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got 2 controllers instantiated. i.e. on 2 separate elements you have:

```
 ng-controller="TokensCtr"
```

The data that you get back from the server will be placed in the $scope variable *tokens* of one controller: the one that the ng-click attribute is in. This is entirely separate to the instance that has the ng-repeat loop over *tokens*.

To solve this, you could have a wrapper div with the ng-controller attribute that contains both the button and the list. If this isn't possible or appropraite, say if they need to be in separate places in the DOM, wrapped by other controllers, you might need to communicate between the controllers using a service or events.

Comment: thank you, I did not realize before now different controller instances have different scopes. it works now :)